# Form of the _recursion theorem_ that motivates the existence of a recursively defined function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, recursion

I'm looking for some form of the [Recursion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) which could motivate the existence of the recursively defined function $F \left ( f \right )$ below.

For any set $A$ define the set of ordered tuples (or ordered lists in the computer science sense) with entries from the set $A$.
For any set $A$
\begin{align*}
    L_0^A &= \left \{ \emptyset \right \} \\
    L_n^A &= \left \{ (x, y): x \in A, \, y \in L_{n-1} \right \} \\
    L(A) &= \bigcup \left \{ L_n^A : n \in \mathbb N \right \}
\end{align*}

Then given $f: A \to B$ I want to motivate the existence of the function $F \left (f \right ): L(A) \to L(B)$ defined by the recursion
$$
F(f)(a) = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \text{if } a = \emptyset \\
 \left ( f(x), F\left (f \right )(y) \right ) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

> Do you have a reference to a form of the Recursion Theorem that could
> be used and a quick pointer to how?

Comment: What do you mean by *motivate* the existence of $F(f)$, is that you want to *prove* the existence of such $F$? In this case, I think what you are doing is trying to prove that the `map` function from LISP/Haskell/etc indeed exists in the mathematical sense. The version in wikipedia link you just given is sufficient; just deal with the recursive construction on the length of list.

Comment: I want to motivate that we indeed can define a function $F(f)$ in this manner. That is, prove - supposedly using the recursion theorem - that $F(f)$ is a set of ordered pairs satisfying the condition for a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using Recursion Theorem as in the wikipedia link. Let $X$ denote the set of all partial functions from $L(A)$ to $L(B)$. We construct a function $$G:\mathbb N\to X\text,$$ such that $G(n)$ is a function $L^A_n\to L^B_n$, as follows:

Define $G_0:L^A_0\to L^B_0$ as the empty function. Define $g:X\to X$ as
$$
g(h)=a \mapsto \begin{cases}
h(a) &\text{ if } a\in\mathrm{dom}(h) \\
(f(x), h(f(y))) &\text{ if } a=(x,y) \text{ and }y\in\mathrm{dom}(h) \\
\varnothing &\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
By recursion theorem, one acquire a function $G$ with $G(0)=G_0$ and $G(n)=g(G(n-1))\restriction L^A_n$. Now, one easily realize that when $a=(x,y)\in L^A_n$, we have $y\in \mathrm{dom}(G(n-1))$ and thus $G(n)(a)=(f(x),G(n-1)(y))$. Also, $G(m)$ coincide with $G(n)$ on the intersection of their domain.

Finally, let $F=\bigcup_n G(n)$. $F$ has the expected properties.

---

However, I believe a direct application of Recursion Theorem like this is lengthy and tedious, if not pedantic. In mathematics $L(A)$ is a well-founded relation, so one can just do recursion on it. This simplify the process to merely one step. You can find more information on Theorem I.9.11 of Kunen's Set Theory (2011 Edition), or [this webpage](https://planetmath.org/wellfoundedrecursion).

Comment: Thanks! One thing that does not make sense to me is the following. If $g : X \to X $ and we consider $g(h)$, then supposedly $\mathrm{dom}(h)=X$. But then $f(y): y \in \mathrm{dom}(h)=X$ does not seem right as $\mathrm{dom}(f)=A$?

Comment: No, the domain of $h$ is not $X$. In fact $h$, as well as $g(h)$, are elements of $X$, namely they are *partial functions* from $L(A)$ to $L(B)$. This means the domain of $h$ is a subset of $L(A)$.